# Django admin - Extended User model

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-modeladmin

My requirement is to create 2 types of user in Django.
1. Student
2. Faculty

I have extended the Django user model by creating a MyProfile model:

```
class MyProfile(models.Model):  
    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #Profile Information
    photo = FilerImageField(
        blank = True,
        help_text = 'Profile Pic',
        null = True,
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL
    )

    #Student Information
    enrollment = models.CharField('Enrollment',
        blank = True,
        default = '',
        help_text = 'Student Enrollment Number',
        max_length = 20,
    )
    admission_date = models.DateField('Admission Date',
        blank = True,
        default = None,
        null = True,
        help_text = 'Date when student joined the college',
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.username)
```

Now if I create a user then
For Student:- Fields likes 'enrollment', 'admission_date' are mandatory BUT
For Faculty:- these fields are not required.

Now in the admin.py file, I did below:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyProfile
    fieldsets = (
        ('Profile Information', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('photo')     
        }),
        ('Student Information', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': (
                ('enrollment', 'admission_date'),
        }).
    )

@admin.register(User)
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_active',)
    inlines = [
        ProfileInline,
    ]
    fieldsets = (
        ('User Information', {
            'fields': ('username', ('first_name', 'last_name'), 'password', 'groups', 'is_active')
        }),
    )
```

I have created 2 groups:
1. student
2. faculty

Now the 1st problem is:
1. If we create a user and select 'student' group then how to check if 'enrollment' & 'admission_date' fields are filled or not. If not then show the error message to user that there are required fields.
2. If we create a user and select 'faculty' group then it should not check for these fields.

2nd problem is:
If you see "MyUserAdmin" class in admin.py, I have included 'password' in fieldsets. When we create user using django admin then it shows the password field as plain input text box. Also it's not hashing the password before saving in database.
1. How I can show 'password' & 'verify password' box.
2. Use password type in input field.
3. Hash the password before saving into the database.

Thanks for the help!

Regards,
Shashank

Comment: This is how you can do custom model validation:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: The admin view use normal forms. So you should supply a modelForm to the modelAdmin and add the password fields and validation of those fields there. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Comment: This is how to set a password https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password

Comment: @allcaps
I can use clean method for model (MyProfile) validation but how can I access the group name that we selected while creating the user?  
For example:  
    `class MyProfile(models.Model):  
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def clean(self):  
        #Check enrollment value based on group selected by user
        #I can access enrollment value but how to access group that we have selected while creating the user
        print self.enrollment`

Comment: No worries. I got the solution for this.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok I think I was in hurry. I'm able to access the user instance from MyProfile clean method which is returning old group that is already saved in the database. I need to access the group that is coming in the current request.
`def clean(self):
self.user.groups.values_list('name',flat=True) `
How can I access the current request in clean method so I can check the group name that been selected?